# Krishna as Dwarkanath, scriptural references?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, name, dwarakanath

I am searching any scriptural references, even mantras, sutras, stotram etc., regarding Krishna as Dwarkanath.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Brahmanda Purana has a stotra recited by Rishi Agastya (in turn recited to him by Shesha) referring Krishna with the epithof "DvarkAnAth".

This hymn, consisting of 108 names of Vishnu is known as the *Kṛṣṇapremāmṛta*

> #### [Chapter 36](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362893.html), Upodghāta-pāda, Brahmanda Purana
>
> अजो निरञ्जनः कामजनकः कञ्जलोचनः ।
>  मधुहा मथुरानाथो **द्वारकानाथ**को बली ॥
> २,३६.३१ ॥
>
> > 31. (51) Aja (The unborn), (52) Nīrañjana the unsullied) (53) Kāmajanaka (father of cupid) i.e. Pradyumna,. (54) Kañjalocana (the
> >     lotus-eyed), (55) Madhuhan (the slayer of demon Madhu), (56)
> >     Mathurānātha (The lord of Mathurā), **(57) Dvārakānātha (the lord of
> >     Dvārakā)**, (58) Balin (the powerful).

---

There's also references in the Garga Samhita

> [Chapter 7](https://archive.org/details/garga-samhita_202103/page/638/mode/1up?view=theater), Khanda 3, Garga-Samhita
>
> जगन्नाथो रंगनाथो **द्वारकानाथ** एव च ।
>  बद्रीनाथश्चतुष्कोणे भारतस्यापि
> पर्वते ॥ ३३ ॥
>
> > 33. On the four corners of the Govardhan hills are the four forms of the Lord viz. Jaggannath, Ranganath, **Dvārakānātha**, and Badrinath.

Comment: Thank You for this. Since Dwarkanath is the original place of Krishna , i expected there was a bigger scriptural reference, as Dwarka is said to be the original kingdom capital of Lord Krishna's kingdom .

Comment: https://www.gujaratexpert.com/dwarka-history/

Comment: Could you kindly clarify what do you mean by "bigger references" @LuckyPashu please?  I mean, there are other references in Harivamsha and Matsya Purana too, if you want I can add them too. However, they too are similar to the ones I pasted above. I assume that Krishna being called DvarkAnAth is apriori and immanent, like Shiva being called Kailashapati. Are you looking for a detailed story as to why he's referred to as DvarkAnAth? If it is so, I think we will be hard pressed to have any such detailed story. Him being called DvarkAnAth is just a natural epithet I think.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Yes , thought it was just not a natural epithet indeed as in Dwarka is represented in that way and my question was basically referred to why he is represented in the above way in Dwarka as Sri Dwarkanath. Shouldn't one of the most ancient representation of Krishna indeed? So I supposed there were some other hymns specifically dedicated to Sri Dwarkanath. Like for Sri Matangi and Sri Saraswati..